# Fetching objects that have To-Many relationship where attribute can be multiple strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I've had a hard time putting together the correct search terms to find this answer, so I thought I'd try to ask it.  I'm still getting to know Core Data.

I have a Player entity and a School entity.  The player has a to-many relationship with schools.

I want all Player objects where the School name attribute can be one of several values (ie, I want all players that have gone to either Stanford, Yale, or Duke).  I imagine that I need to use the 'IN' clause, something like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"schools.name IN ("%@", "%@", "%@"), @"Stanford", @"Yale", @"Duke"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't quote inside the predicate format string

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY schools.name IN (%@, %@, %@)", @"Stanford", @"Yale", @"Duke"];
```

but this is a useless bit of code.  Given an NSArray of names then I believe you can do this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY schools.name IN %@", arrayOfNames];
```

Comment: I'm getting a 
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate"
The inverse relationship from School to Player is also to-many. Could that be the problem?

Comment: My mistake, missed the ANY.  Answer amended.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it.

```m
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY schools IN %@", schoolObjectArray];
```

The relationship from Player to Schools is schools, and the schoolObjectArray contains the School NSManagedObjects that I want.

Answer (score 0):

maybe?

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"schools.name IN (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", @"Stanford", @"Yale", @"Duke"];
```

Comment: Never quote inside the format string unless you want to match against a string that starts and end with quotes.